# Loading javascript for IE7.. What's my big 'Don't'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, instantiation, internet-explorer-7

I started debugging my application in IE7 recently, and noticed a **ton** of jQuery and javascript is not loading properly. But if I take snippets of the specific function out of my javascript.js file and hard-code them at the bottom of the page I'm working on.. it ends up working!

My big question is what **one step** can I take to make it so that my jQuery and javascript loads appropriately from its respective external file?

Here's an example of my .js file. This is just a small snippet exmaple, of when I removed this from this file and hard-coded it at the bottom of the page it was being called to it, it worked. Also note that all of my code works perfectly in IE8, safari, chrome, and firefox.

```
//javascript.js

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
  $(".close_facebox").live("click", function(){
    $.facebox.close();
  });
});
```

And my custom javascripts are all instantiated in their proper hierarchy of importance. jQuery first, then the master libraries, down to my custom mini scripts last.

**Update**

Here is a copy of my head :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='content-type' />
  <title>HQchannel</title>
  <meta content='Local, New Jersey, Promotions, Coupons, Deals, Businesses, telephone, North Jersey' name='keywords' />
  <meta content='Your local guide to events, promotions, and every local company near you. We are local search made wonderful.' name='description' />
  <meta content='6670644BEAA93299A81158F71F517217' name='msvalidate.01' />
  <meta content='c89c098960f9f17d' name='y_key' />

  <link href="/stylesheets/reset.css?1280427413" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/text.css?1265032682" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/960.css?1265032682" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/main.css?1289324536" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/dynamic_stylesheets/image_css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![if !(IE 6)]>
  <link href="/stylesheets/not-ie6.css?1270651849" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]>
  <!--[if IE 7]> 
    <link href="/stylesheets/is-ie7.css?1276194187" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->

  <![if !(IE)]>
  <link href="/stylesheets/not-ie.css?1278686676" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]>
  <link href="/stylesheets/themes/main-booger/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css?1267136221" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/facebox.css?1289316781" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js?1267136221" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/swfobject.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.dirtyform.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1289316793" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.updater.js?1268851685" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.periodicalupdater.js?1268851685" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/easyTooltip.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="/javascripts/easySlider.js?1267136221" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/facebox.js?1289316781" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link href='/images/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' />
  <link href="/stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css?1265032682" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css?1265032683" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/panda_uploader/panda-uploader.css?1272561465" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js?1267136221" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/swfupload.js?1265032682" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.swfupload.js?1280435993" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/manage.js?1289316781" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?1281027480" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="/panda_uploader/jquery.panda-uploader-1.0.1.min.js?1289316781" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please show some additional sample code, like your `<script>` tags that include your script files?

Comment: Is someone leaving off the closing </script> tag with the external files?

Comment: Are all your scripts in the `<head>` section of your site?

Comment: @surreal, Its kind of pointless. Not all of my javascript is affected, but most of it is. The above is a very simple one that is being ignored. @epascarello, no it can't be because i'm using HAML, it auto closes all my tags. @marko yes all of it is in my head file.

Comment: I mean even before that code - the script tags that load your jQuery library, like `<script type="xxxxxx" src="yyyyyy"></script>`.  Or link us to a URL, that's usually the best and simplest way, if you are able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you have some syntax that chokes IE7 but not other browsers. This one bit me a couple of times

```
var myLookup = {a: "a", b: "b",};
```

Other browsers take that trailing `,` but not IE7.

Anyway, here's how I'd narrow it down. It's the pain-in-the-ass-binary-file-search method. Start by completely clearing out your javascript.js file. Load the page. Any errors? Probably not. Now replace half of your javascript.js file. Any errors? If not, then your problem is probably in the half you removed. Have errors? Then you've probably got an error in the half you put back. Remove half of the half and see if that causes errors and so on. Eventually you'll narrow it down to one dumb little thing that IE7 doesn't like, you'll change 1 line of code, and be in a terrible mood.

Comment: @Trip If you are having this kind of problem in future, run your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), which can help you identify defects in your code. It will show you a lot of other things that don't really matter as well, but an automated way of finding syntax issues has to be better than a manual way!

Comment: @lonesomeday That found out my exact problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Also, FYI, you're including some files more than once.  Some of your conditional IE comments are not correctly formatted.  They go like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>  //do stuff  <![endif]-->
```

You left out the `--` in the IE6 comments but your IE7 comments are correct.